# Does MYSql Community edition support Nosql

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, express, mysql-workbench

I am planning to learn and built a Nodejs application with Sql and i know that MySql Enterprise Edition supports the NoSql, but does community edition supports Nosql or it is that i have to purchase enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Community edition supports document store (NoSQL) and also Maria DB does 
it's documented here

- MYSQL: https://www.mysql.com/products/community/
- MariaDb: https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/the-best-of-both-worlds/

Answer (score -1):

Create a table with a 2 columns: 'key' and 'value'. Now it's NoSQL.